# Styling Inline Troubles

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style - on one line - a group of buttons on the left, a navigation list in the middle, and a group of buttons on the right. I have grouped the navigation buttons for when the layout should change. Question is how to get the navigation structure on the same line in the center of the parent element?

I have made both overarching div elements into "display: inline" elements, and also the navigation.

- Do I need to use absolute positioning of the nav for this to work? Why?
- How can I center the nav horizontally?

My HTML:

```css
  // you need to have font smoothing on to avoid blurred and jagged lines 
    html{
        background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    }
    
    #main_body{
        width: 1200px;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: white;
    }
    
    // first line header styling 
    #header_topnav{
        width: 96%;
        height: fit-content;
    }
    
    // button div, navigation and button div 
    .topnav_button{
        width: 45px;
        height: 35px;
        margin-top: 18px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    // make div inline element to get it on one line
    #left_buttons{
        display: inline;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    // make div inline element to get it on one line
    // no other way than to go with left or margin 
    #right_buttons{
        display: inline;
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 87.5%;
        // left: 86.5%;
    }
    
    // vertical centering 
    ul {
        margin: auto;
    }
    
    // for horizontal nav menu 
    li {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    
    // display block so clickable area is larger 
    li a {
        display: block;
      }
    
    // how do you center this horizontally? 
    // do I have to make position absolute? can't I keep it in between the button sections?
    #top_navmenu {
        position: absolute;    
        display: inline;
        margin-top: 28px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="main_body">
    <header>
        <section id="header_topnav">
            <div id="left_buttons">
            <button class="topnav_button"></button>
                <button class="topnav_button"></button>
            </div>

            <nav id="top_navmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a>F+</a></li>
                    <li><a>POLITIK</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div id="right_buttons">
                <button class="topnav_button"></button>
            </div>
        </section>
    </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `position: absolute`. You can achieve this with flexbox.

Just add `display:flex` on the wrapper ( `#header_topnav` ) and `flex-grow: 1` on the middle menu. This way the menu will occupy all the available space between the left and right buttons.

Also when sharing code here on SO please be sure you share valid code.

- HTML code is missing some closing tags
- `//` is not a valid comment in CSS. Use `/* comment */` instead.

See below

```css
html {
  background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
}

#main_body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;

}

#header_topnav {
  height: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}


.topnav_button {
  width: 45px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


#left_buttons {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}


#right_buttons {
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}


li a {
  display: block;
}


#top_navmenu {
  margin-top: 28px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

}
```

```html
<div id="main_body">
  <header>
    <section id="header_topnav">
      <div id="left_buttons">
        <button class="topnav_button"></button>
        <button class="topnav_button"></button>
      </div>

      <nav id="top_navmenu">
        <ul>
          <li><a>F+</a></li>
          <li><a>POLITIK</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <div id="right_buttons">
        <button class="topnav_button"></button>
      </div>
    </section>
  </header>
</div>
```